# how to resolve conflict of ActorSystem in akka http test and akka test kit

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest, akka-http, akka-testkit

i have a test class in which i need to use both [akka testkit](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/testing.html) and [akka http test kit](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/testkit.html)
so i am doing it like this

```
class MyTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testsys")) with ScalaFutures with ImplicitSender with AnyWordSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll with ScalatestRouteTest { 

//tests here
}
```

but i am getting a compile time error

```
implicit val system: akka.actor.ActorSystem (defined in class TestKit) and
[error]   implicit val system: akka.actor.ActorSystem (defined in trait RouteTest)
[error]   (note: this can be resolved by declaring an `override` in class MyTest.)
[error] class InsertEventTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testinterpret")) with ScalaFutures with ImplicitSender with AnyWordSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll with ScalatestRouteTest {
[error]       ^

(note: this can be resolved by declaring an `override` in class InsertEventTest.)
```

so i did something like this

```
    class MyTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testsys")) with ScalaFutures with ImplicitSender with AnyWordSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll with ScalatestRouteTest { 
override def createActorSystem(): ActorSystem = system
  override implicit val system: ActorSystem = createActorSystem

    //tests here
    }
```

but i am getting `NullPointerException`

```
Java.lang.NullPointerException: system must not be null!
[info]   at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:246)
[info]   at akka.actor.ExtensionId.apply(Extension.scala:78)
[info]   at akka.actor.ExtensionId.apply$(Extension.scala:77)
[info]   at akka.testkit.TestKitExtension$.apply(TestKitExtension.scala:14)
[info]   at akka.testkit.TestKitBase.$init$(TestKit.scala:161)
[info]   at akka.testkit.TestKit.<init>(TestKit.scala:928)
[info]   at MyTest.<init>(MyTest.scala:40)
[info]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[info]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

here is the documents of [TestKit](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/testkit/TestKit.html) and [RouteTest](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.1.11/akka/http/scaladsl/testkit/RouteTest.html)

Comment: Why do you have a test for both `TestKit` and `RouteTest`? That just seems design flaw. Those two test types are not designed to coexist in the same class. Can you separate them into 2 test classes?